# PHP if Month Equals then Echo CSS Style

Tags: php, date, loops

I would normally do this sort of thing in jQuery, but this will require a server side touch.  I am new to PHP and need assistance writing a basic script that will take in a numerical month `the_time('m')` and I simply wish to say if it equals 01 then `echo "#000"` and then loop through the other months 02, 03 ,04, so on and have them echo different hex codes if the month is equal.

Forgive my crude and incorrect code, but I thought this would help visualize the solution I am working towards.

```
style="background: #
<?php 
if(the_time('m') == "01") { 
    echo "000";
} else if (the_time('m') == "02"){
    echo "111";
} // so on through 12
?>
"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT
The while loop code I am currently inside:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$code = "f5f5f5"; // Set default
$month = the_time('m');

switch ($month) {
        case "01" :
    $code = "f5f5f5";
            break;

    case "02" :
    $code = "f3f3f3";
    break;

    case "03" :
    $code = "f1f1f1";
    break;

    case "04" :
    $code = "efefef";
    break;

    }
?>

<li id="event_<?php the_time('m_d_Y') ?>" style="background: #<?php echo $code ?>;">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't really go down that path, but I'd do something like:

```
<div class="month-<?php echo strtolower(date('M')) ?>">Howdy</div>

// your CSS file:
.month-jan { background: #000; }
.month-feb { background: #FFF; }
// etc
```

Comment: Works great!  Exactly what I needed, just plain and simple.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
$code = "000"; // Set default
$month = date ( "m" );

switch ($month) {
    case "02" :
        $code = "111";
        break;

    case "03" :
        $code = "CCC";
        break;

    case "04" :
        $code = "FFF";
        break;

}
?>
style="background: #<?php echo $code ?>"
```

Comment: Your example is great using a switch.  I have this in a php while loop and my background color are always returning to the default and not the correct month hex code.  I'm going to add some code to question above to show you.

Comment: seen ... are you saying you still need help ??? I can see you have accepted an answer already ???

Comment: I am set.  I decided the solution above would be more suitable to my needs.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (date('n')) {
    case 1:
        echo "000";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "111";
        break;
    ...
}
```

Or, simpler:

```
$colors = array(
    1 => "000",
    2 => "111",
    ...
);
echo $colors[date('n')];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the month with php's date function, subtract one, convert to hex, and repeat it 3 times.

```
echo printf('%1$'.base_convert(date('n') - 1, 10, 16).'3d', date('n') - 1);
```

It's a little tricky and obtuse, but you avoid needing a `switch` or a huge chunk of `elseif`s